# automated deployment does not work

Tags: tfs, web-deployment

I have setup an automated build in tfs 2012. When I publish my asp.net application it gets deployed fine. Can I somehow import/use the publishing profile (.pubxml file) to be used in my buildprocess template?

I got this in my template:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your build template, process section, go to msbuild arguments part and give the following

```
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=local;AllowUntrustedCertificate=true;UserName=myuser;Password=mypw
```

Comment: tried it does not work? I can see the build log which is fine, is there a deployment log too?

Comment: is your publish profile name is stage? you have to give the same publish profile name that you created in your project file.

Comment: yes mine is called 'local' . When I run this through the commandline it works: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe mysol.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=local.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=myuser  /p:Password=mypw

Comment: then give the same settings in your msbuild arguments. it will work. i Changed my answer.

Comment: still not working:( I am using the defaulttemplate in the buildprocess template , do I need to change this too?

Comment: The default template is enough for the Web publish. is your publish profile type is Web Deploy?  if you still facing problem, check the corresponding log files in the Build agent machine.

Comment: I ran the buildscript on the build machine and the difference with the local log is that there is no deploy being done??